# How to move BizTalk EAI services from on premises to Logic Apps which is using TCP/IP custom adaptors(designed by codeplex)

Tags: azure-logic-apps

We have BizTalk EAI application which received request and send response to client using sokect switching (TCP/IP adaptors designed by codeplex) . 
We need help to move EAI application from in premises to Logic Apps. Could anyone assist us to implement socket switching (TCP/IP adaptors/connectors or triggers) to receive request and sending response back to client

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a notable gap in the available Connectors right now.

You best option is to stand up a Azure VM with a BizTalk Server instance to host this Adapter.  You can connect it to the Logic Apps through Service Bus, Logic App Adapter or such.